# Exporting Database Using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm attempting to switch from Third-Party Hosting to In House hosting. I have all sites but one transferred. The last one I'm having issues with involves some plugins. I'm asking the plugin programmer for a new download, and was told that I have to export the database.

My question is: is there a way to export every concept of the database including Column Headers. I'm wanting to export the whole database, so when I import it into my SQL Server I don't have to do anything, just go into WordPress import the setups for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have access to your current database **phpMyAdmin**

1. Log in to it
2. Select the desired database from the left menu
3. You should see an **Export** tab in the right panel, click it
4. In **Export Method** you can leave it as *Quick*
5. Export it as **SQL**
6. Press **GO** (the submit button)

> If you happen to have any problem downloading the export, try using the **custom** method and selecting one compression (gzipped for example) method.

Then, importing the database is the inverse process into your new Database.

1. Login to your new database phpMyAdmin
2. Select your newly created DB
3. Click **Import** tab
4. Select the file to upload
5. **Go**

> **Make sure** your new database is **EMPTY** if you want to migrate **ALL THE TABLES**. If you want to just migrate a few tables, you can select them in the custom method and then import only those.
>
> **Make sure** you are running the same Wordpress files with your DB data, or you may experience many inconsistencies.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work as this is what was done to begin with. I figured out the answer and got a new download for the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue was fixed with a new download of the plugin.